# Which one is faster/better/more memory efficient?

Tags: java, performance, memory

I have some old software programmed by someone else which i am looking into.
Quite often i see code similar to this example, which i assume is not the best way to do it:

```
public Map<String, Sheet> getCalcedSheets() {
   Sheet mySheet = this.doSomeBigCalculationsAndGiveMeMySheet();
   return mySheet;
}
```

Wouldnt it better not to initiliaze a Instance of the Class Sheet, and just return what the method gives you back?
Like this:

```
public Map<String, Sheet> getCalcedSheets() throws Exception {
    return this.doSomeBigCalculationsAndGiveMeMySheet();;
}
```

I think this would be more CPU friendly because no instance of Sheet would be initialized.
And also mySheet  wouldnt be garbage collected immediatly after creation.

What do you think?

Comment: They're exactly the same. Neither creates more objects than the other. One of them has an extra local variable, but that doesn't have any effect on the code's behaviour. Use whichever is clearer to read.

Comment: `mySheet` is a *reference*. References aren't gc'd, only objects are. There's absolutely no difference whatsoever in the performance. The **only** difference is in the amount of lines in the source code. Even the bytecode generated is the same. Don't try to optimize by guessing, you're unlikely to guess correctly.

Comment: @Kayaman Not 100% correct, bytecode is different (using OpenJDK 13 compiler) and stack usage too. Maybe JIT does eliminate it when run, See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/CHeuberger/09b8e3b86e609c959d9b163a6d77f5c8)

Comment: @user85421 well JIT definitely will. I made the mistake of assuming. I guess the old adage still holds true, `javac` doesn't optimize.

Comment: @Kayaman wouldn't be good, e.g. for *tools* that rely on byte code weaving or so (AspectJ, Mockito, ...)

Answer (score 0):

the mySheet object is a reference from the stack to the real object. which means, that when the stack is done (function end), the pointer will no longer be exists (the garbage collector is not clean up the stack - only heap memory)